# Servlet Filters does not work before extracting a For loop to a method

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

I'm trying to write a servlet filter that intercepts to all requests that need login.

This is My Filter:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "LoginNeedCustomerFilter", urlPatterns = "/*")
public class LoginNeedCustomerFilter implements Filter {

    private FilterConfig filterConfig;
    private static final String[] needToLoginUrls = {"/view_profile", "/edit_profile", "/update_profile",
            "/write_review", "/checkout", "/place_order", "/view_orders", "/show_order_detail"};


    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpSession existedSession = request.getSession(false);

        String contextPath = filterConfig.getServletContext().getContextPath();
        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();

        if (requestURI.startsWith(contextPath + "/admin/")) {

            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
            return;
        }

        boolean isLoggedIn = (existedSession != null) && (existedSession.getAttribute("theCustomer") != null);

        if (!isLoggedIn) {

            for (String loginRequiredURL : needToLoginUrls) {
                if (requestURI.contains(loginRequiredURL)) {

                    String destination = "frontend/login.jsp";
                    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher(destination);
                    dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
                }

            }
        }
        
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }


    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfig = config;
    }
}
```

but this code does not work and throw this exception:

```
05-Jan-2021 04:53:24.040 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-14] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [ShowEditProfileFormServlet] in context with path [/MehdiSarfBookStore_war_exploded] threw exception
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:456)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.doGet(HttpServlet.java:174)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.mehdisarf.mehdisarfbookstore.controller.frontend.customer.LoginNeedCustomerFilter.doFilter(LoginNeedCustomerFilter.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.mehdisarf.mehdisarfbookstore.controller.frontend.category.GetCategoriesFilter.doFilter(GetCategoriesFilter.java:36)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

**But** when I extract the `for` loop to a method, and change the condition of outter `if`, everythings will be ok. like this:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "LoginNeedCustomerFilter", urlPatterns = "/*")
public class LoginNeedCustomerFilter implements Filter {

    private FilterConfig filterConfig;
    private static final String[] needToLoginUrls = {"/view_profile", "/edit_profile", "/update_profile",
            "/write_review", "/checkout", "/place_order", "/view_orders", "/show_order_detail"};


    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpSession existedSession = request.getSession(false);

        String contextPath = filterConfig.getServletContext().getContextPath();
        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();

        if (requestURI.startsWith(contextPath + "/admin/")) {

            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
            return;
        }

        boolean isLoggedIn = (existedSession != null) && (existedSession.getAttribute("theCustomer") != null);


        if (!isLoggedIn && this.isLoginRequired(requestURI)) {


            String destination = "frontend/login.jsp";
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher(destination);
            dispatcher.forward(req, resp);

        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        }
    }

    private boolean isLoginRequired(String requestURL) {
        for (String loginRequiredURL : needToLoginUrls) {
            if (requestURL.contains(loginRequiredURL)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfig = config;
    }
}
```

why? what is the difference between these two code that one of them will cause problem in running my program.

Thanks.

Comment: Where/how did `requestURL` (in `doFilter`) get set (NOT `requestURI`)?

Comment: @JimGarrison sorry, it was typo. I edited the code.

Comment: That implies that what you posted was typed in, not copy/pasted.  In that case all bets are off as we cannot be sure what you posted matches what is actually running.  tl;dr: Always copy/paste, never retype code.

Comment: @JimGarrison yes, you're right. of course after that, I put the code in a ide and now i'm sure that it doesn't have problems like typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first (non-working) code you return from `RequestDispatcher#forward()` and continue on to `chain.doFilter()`, while in the second (working) code you do one or the other but not both.

Comment: could you please recommend me some good book about Servlets and Enterprise edition? ( servlet headfirst and murach's servlet were just fine but they were not so deep in my opinion )